# Django error noneType

Tags: django

I don't know why i got this error. What does it mean?

I have this site into a virtual machine and is running inside a webserver platform. Is this maybe due to the fact that the site is not hosted directly?

```
[26/Jan/2018 16:28:52] "GET /static/css/custom.css HTTP/1.1" 200 7346
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 137, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 67, in __call__
    return super().__call__(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 146, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 62, in get_response
    return super().get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 81, in get_response
    response = self._middleware_chain(request)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
[26/Jan/2018 16:28:52] "GET /static/css/bootstrap.min.css.map HTTP/1.1" 500 59
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 137, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 67, in __call__
    return super().__call__(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 146, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 62, in get_response
    return super().get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 81, in get_response
    response = self._middleware_chain(request)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Comment: Have you added your host ip in `ALLOWED HOSTS`?

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere, you have a variable which is not set properly, and django is attempting to call on it.

You can reproduce the error like this:

```
>>> a = None
>>> a()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
    a()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

As for  why it is happening in your application, that's very hard to tell without you showing any code. If you are not sure where the error is, I suggest trying to undo recent changes until it starts working again.

A quick stab in the dark is that some of your middleware is  not configured properly.